# How to avoid resource-hunger in WindowGetText using String Builder?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I am using the WindowGetText function in VB.net to get the text from a chatroom windows. But as the text continuously builds up, after a few hours, my app freezeed and throwed up an exceptional error. I use one StringBuilder to get text and then load it to a textbox to see the chatroom text.

```
dim sb as New System.Text.StringBuilder
GetWindowText(chatroomHandle, sb, sb.Capacity)
ChatroomTxt.Text=sb.toString
```

I realize the problem could occur when my **ChatroomTxt textbo**x reached its maximum capacity. And, also the use of unmanaged StringBuilder like this will result in a **resource hungry** application.

How could I solve those problems~.
Thank you very much ~

Comment: You could save each line to a list(of String) and load the portion you want to read into the text box maybe? To move through the file, just change the keydown handleer to handle the up and down and pgup and pgdn keys.

Comment: Thank you @David, I would try to follow that and get back to this topic with the code. Thank you very much~

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant that you should save the text to a file rather than a list. Duh!